# How can I tell Angular not to compile child nodes when using $compile

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

The situation is I have an HTML structure somewhat similar to this:

```
<div class="dynamicDirectiveGoesHere">
    <p>{{SomeExpressionThatDiffers}}</p>
</div>
```

I need to display a bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ popover when the text within p has an ellipsis. That's why I'm adding the popover attribute dynamically. I can get the popover to display using $compile, but the problem is the text within {{ }} goes away. I can't use the template trick since I don't really know what the template will be since the popover will happen on several different child tags that have different templates. So that's why there is the need to only $compile what's in div, and not in the child element (p tag). Is this possible with angular?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property `terminal` to your directive and adjust the priority to fit your needs.

`terminal: true` prevents other directives from getting instantiated and is used by for example the `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` directive.

You can read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile (scroll down to terminal).